# Operating System wasn't found

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I was trying to boot my USB to install Windows on another PC. After finishing my boot process, I turned off my current computer.

When I turned it on, it is showing the error

> An Operating System wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

This is my main PC containing a lot of data.
Please help!
How can I turn it on without reinstalling Windows on it?

Comment: Sounds like you have a usb plugged in that's marked bootable but doesn't have an os installed? Remove any usb drives/sticks and reboot your machine.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying. You were trying to install an operating system on another computer. What, exactly, did you do on your current computer? … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.